# How can I read two bytes from two Registers in a Device within i2c?

Tags: byte, i2c

Currently - I am following the below steps to read multiple bytes from multiple registers -

1. Make a START sequence
2. Send 1010XXX0, where XXX is the direction of the IC to use, wait for ACK
3. Send the low byte_0 of the register address to be read, wait for ACK
4. Send the high byte_0 of the register  address to be read, wait for ACK
5. Send the low byte_0 of the register  address to be read, wait for ACK
6. Send the high byte_1 of the  register  address to be read, wait for ACK
7. Make a START sequence
8. Send 1010XXX1, where XXX is the direction of the IC to use, wait for ACK
9. Read byte_0, send an ACK to the memory
10. Read byte_1, send an ACK to the memory
11. Send a nack
12. When no more bytes need to be read, send a STOP sequence

[. Example I2C Read from Slave Device's Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeGVJ.png)

However, I am not able to read two bytes, and only one byte can be read.

What is the correct process to read both the bytes from both the 0x0000 and 0x0001 register?

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the [I2C-bus specification](https://ullisroboterseite.de/i2c-werkstatt/UM10204.pdf) from [NXP](https://www.nxp.com/):

General comment: There is no XXX *direction* specification in the I2C Addressing. All 7 bits are the address of the slave. The eighth bit tells the device whether this will be a *write* (0, master write bytes to slave) or a *read* (1, slave writes bytes to master) operation.

Having said that, reading two bytes at 0x0000 and 0x0001 should work like that:

- Tell device to go to the first byte:

1. Start condition (S)
2. Slave adress (7 bits, XXXXXXX)
3. Write intent (1 bit, "0")
4. ACK by slave
5. Send first adress byte to device (8 bits, "00000000")
6. ACK by slave
7. Send second adress byte to device (8 bits, "00000000")
8. ACK by slave

- Now, the slave should be pointing at first byte you want to read, i.e. 0x0000. From here, you should be able to successively read both bytes from the device

9. Repeated Start condition (same as Start)
10. Slave adress (7 bits, XXXXXXX)
11. Read intent (1 bit, "1")
12. ACK by slave
13. Read first byte from slave (the slave should now automatically jump to the next byte)
14. ACK by master
15. Read second byte from slave
16. NACK by master (to end transfer)
17. Stop condition (P)

Here's an image of the communication flow described above:

[image: i2c_read_two_bytes_communication]